# Dividing Binomial Coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have a problem which requires multiplying:

$$
\frac 1 4 \cdot \binom n k
$$

Expanded: 
$$
\frac 1 4 \cdot \frac {(n)!} {5!(n-5)!}
$$

The answer is below, but it isn't clear how to get from the initial state to this one algebraically.
$$
\frac {(n-1)!} {4!(n-5)!}
$$

Comment: have you typed everything correctly?

Comment: is n=20 and k=5?

Comment: That's because you can't.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes Viram, n=20. I'm not sure how to get from one the original equation to the other one algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=20$ then $$\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{n!}{5!\cdot(n-5)!}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{20!}{5!\cdot15!}=\frac{20\cdot19!}{4\cdot5\cdot4!\cdot15!}=\frac{19!}{4!\cdot15!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{4!\cdot(n-5)!}$$

Comment: Would there be any way to derive the solution without knowing n = 20?

Comment: It's simply either not true for $n\neq 20$, or the requirements for it to be true result in something not very useful.